# Where are the build settings in Homebrew?

Tags: macos, homebrew

I'm looking for a a settings file in Homebrew for OS X that controls the build settings, similar to `make.conf` in Gentoo.

I want to tweak the `make -j` parameter to use more cores of my machine. The problem is, I can't find anything useful related to brew in `/usr/local/etc`. Is there a simple answer to this?

Comment: Each brew has its own recipe for making. These are usually ruby files, IIRC. You can certainly customize them, but there are no system wide homewbrew settings that I know of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @jakev said, each Homebrew formula is a separate Ruby script. You can find them at

> [`https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tree/master/Library/Formula`](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/tree/master/Library/Formula)

If you want to edit the way a specific formula builds, you can do that locally. The following will open your default editor with the locally cached formula.

```
brew edit name-of-formula
```

The reason for the absence of global build settings is simply that each formula might build in different ways, and editing yourself ("homebrewing") is explicitly encouraged.

Comment: That's an interesting design decision, since it would make sense to store some parameters, such as the "-j" build option globally. MacPorts seems more structured (if less flexible) in this sense.